# Dividing 12 students into classes of 4

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways can you divide 12 students in 3 distinct classes, if a maximum number of students in each class is 4?

If I pick 4 students out of 12 for the first class in C(12,4) ways, then C(8,4) and C(4,4), do I need to divide my result with 3! ? Would dividing by 3! mean that I make no difference between the classes and think of them as three indistinct groups?

Comment: Btw your point about dividing by $3!$ is correct. If you divide, there is no distinction between classes - it is just making groups of different people.

Comment: @MathLover I edited my question, I need exactly 3 classes. I was wondering if dividing by 3! makes my classes indistinct or if that means I don't care in what order my classes were filled. Thanks

Comment: May be make it explicit that it matters which classes students go to and hence your answer is not divided by $3!$.

Comment: Isn’t it just 12!?  Each of the permutation of 12 students is a valid class assignment. Since there are 12 spots

Comment: @GopalAnantharaman but the order of students inside of each class doesn't matter. The result might be correct for these conditions, but I am not sure using the same method if restrictions were different would get us a corrrect result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on whether the classes are labeled.  If we only care about which students are in the same class, then dividing by $3!$ is appropriate.  However, if the classes are labeled, you should not divide by $3!$ since it matters which class which student takes.  Since the classes in your problem are distinct, you should not divide by $3!$ in this case.  The correct answer is
$$\binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\binom{4}{4}$$